# Tooltip disappears when moving leaflet map

Tags: events, leaflet, popup, tooltip, leaflet.markercluster

I add markers to the map and place them in the markercluster. For markers that are not clustered, I want to show the tooltip that I attach to the marker when I create it.

```
var geoMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({ removeOutsideVisibleBounds:true, chunkedLoading: true, chunkProgress: this._updateProgress });

//start loop create markers
var marker = new L.marker(latlng, { icon: icon } );
marker.bindPopup(L._("Loading.."));
marker.bindTooltip(' text ');
geoMarkers.addLayer(marker);
//end loop


map.addLayer(geoMarkers);

map.on('layeradd', function(event) {
    var layer = event.layer;

    if (layer instanceof L.Marker && !(layer instanceof L.MarkerCluster)) {
        layer.openTooltip();
    }
});
```

To do this, I followed advice and listen for the layeradd event. When loading the map and moving to new markers, everything works. However, at any movement of the map, on those markers where the tooltip is already open, it is closed, since the layeradd event does not affect them. There is only one way to see the hint on them again - to zoom out so that the marker "hides" in the cluster and then again increasing the scale, I see the hint again. It is desirable that it be always present when the marker is not hidden in the cluster.
I ask for help or hints.

Comment: What about making the tooltip permanent? `marker.bindTooltip(' text , { permanent: true }');
`

Comment: @kboul A good idea! And then I can remove the listener. I didn’t look this way as I have to periodically switch markers to non-interactive mode. With a large number of markers, of course, there will be too many tips, but a good idea. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `permanent` tooltip option in order to maintain the visibility of your marker. Check here for official [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tooltip-permanent).

```
...
var geoMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({ removeOutsideVisibleBounds:true, chunkedLoading: true, chunkProgress: this._updateProgress });

//start loop create markers
var marker = new L.marker(latlng, { icon: icon } );
marker.bindPopup(L._("Loading.."));
marker.bindTooltip(' text ', { permanent: true} ); // here define it
geoMarkers.addLayer(marker);
//end loop
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I already had `permanent: true` but the tooltips disappeared, anyway. I did not explore further *why* that bug happens … (Too much customization?)

… But here is a fix: identify the tooltips in a bad state and simply reopen them.

```js
let bringBackMissingPermaTooltips = (map) => {
  if ((map instanceof L.Map) === false) {
    return;
  }

  let targets = Object.values(map._targets);
  let elementsWithBrokenTooltips = targets.filter((el) => 
  el._tooltip?.options?.permanent === true && el.isTooltipOpen() === false);
  elementsWithBrokenTooltips.forEach((el) => el.openTooltip());
}

map.on('moveend', () => {
  bringBackMissingPermaTooltips(map);
});
```